Recovering the electromagnetic field from the $(1,0) \oplus (0,1)$ representation
I'm confused as to how one recovers the electromagnetic field $E,B$ from the standard procedure of building the $(1,0) \oplus (0,1)$ representation of the Lorentz Lie algebra. The reason is the following:
For the irreducible $(1,0)$ we have an obvious choice of representation for the generators $\pi(J_i^{(1,0)}) = \epsilon_{ijk} $, and it's complexification $\pi(K_i^{(1,0)}) = i\epsilon_{ijk}$. Similar for $(0,1)$ but with some signs exchanged. Our electromagnetic field should then tranform according to the (exponencial of the) direct sum $\pi(J^{(1,0)}) \oplus \pi(J^{(0,1)})$ of these irreps, such as the direct sum of the boosts generators $K_z^{(1,0)} \oplus K_z^{(0,1)}$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & i & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-i & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -i & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & i & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
If one naively associates a vector with the e.m. fields like $\Psi = (\overrightarrow{E},\overrightarrow{B})$, the above transformation is not going to generate the correct boost. How do I recover $E,B$ in a 6 dimensional vector following this procedure? Also the imaginary unit in the generator makes me think that if I change to the correct basis in some complex vector I can recover the fields but I'm lost.

I am quite confused about what is going on here. The $(1,0)\oplus (0,1)$ representation is the anti-symmetric $2$-covariant tensor representation (i.e. $2$-forms). An object in this representation is some $F_{\mu\nu}$ from which electric and magnetic fields can be defined as usual: $E^i = F^{0i}$ and $B^i = \epsilon^{ijk}F_{jk}$.

WP.

@Gold Yes, that's how we usually view the (1,0) + (0,1) rep. But I was wondering if we can build a 6 dim representation that does not involve the antisymmetic tensor.

The $(1,0)$ representation is $F_{(\alpha\beta)}$ and the $(0,1)$ representation is $F_{({\dot \alpha}{\dot \beta})}$. The field strength in spacetime is then given by
$$
F_{\mu\nu} = (\sigma_{\mu\nu})^{\alpha\beta} F_{\alpha\beta} + ( {\bar  \sigma}_{\mu\nu} )^{{\dot \alpha}{\dot \beta}} F_{{\dot \alpha}{\dot \beta}} . 
$$
Thus, $F_{\mu\nu}$ lives in the $(1,0) \oplus(0,1)$ representation. From this, you can extract $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$.
PS -- We have the definitions.
$$
(\sigma_{\mu\nu})_\alpha{}^\beta = \frac{1}{4} ( \sigma_\mu {\bar \sigma}_\nu - \sigma_\nu {\bar \sigma}_\mu )_\alpha{}^\beta , \qquad ( {\bar \sigma}_{\mu\nu} )^{\dot \alpha}{}_{\dot \beta} = \frac{1}{4} ( {\bar \sigma}_\mu \sigma_\nu - {\bar \sigma}_\nu \sigma_\mu )^{\dot \alpha}{}_{\dot \beta} ,
$$
and
$$
(\sigma^\mu)_{\alpha{\dot \beta}} = ( 1 , \vec{\sigma} ) , \qquad ( {\bar \sigma}^\mu )^{{\dot \alpha}\beta} = ( 1 , - \vec{\sigma} ) . 
$$
Spinor indices are raised and lowered using the Levi-Civita tensor $\varepsilon_{\alpha\beta}$ and $\varepsilon_{\dot \alpha \dot \beta}$.

The $(1,0)\oplus (0,1)$ representation is the $2$-covariant anti-symmetric tensor representation $$F = \frac{1}{2}F_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu\wedge dx^\nu.$$
Moreover, the $F_{\mu\nu}$ are already the components of the electric and magnetic fields. In other words: $$F_{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & E_1 & E_2 & E_3\\ -E_1 & 0 & - B_3 & B_2 \\ -E_2 & B_3  & 0 & - B_1\\ -E_3 & - B_2   & B_1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$
You seem to want to "flatten" this matrix and turn it into a row vector $(E_1,E_2,E_3,B_1,B_2,B_3)$. This is obviously doable by just relabeling the basis vectors of the representation.
For example, take the following choice $$\theta^1 = dx^0\wedge dx^1,\quad \theta^2 = dx^0\wedge dx^2,\quad \theta^3 = dx^0\wedge dx^3,\quad \theta^4=dx^3\wedge dx^2,\quad \theta^5= dx^1\wedge dx^3,\quad \theta^6=dx^1\wedge dx^2. $$
Then $$F = E_1 \theta^1+E_2\theta^2+E_3\theta^3 + B_1\theta^4+B_2\theta^5+B_3\theta^6.$$
This is totally trivial though, you are working with the same object and you don't even have some non-trivial change of basis anyway.

After some calculations I found what I wanted. We can take the change-of-basis matrix $P$ to be
\begin{gather}
P = \frac{1}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 &0 &-i & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -i & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &-i\\
-i & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -i & 0 &0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -i & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}
such that in the new basis $\Psi' = P \Psi = (\overrightarrow{E},\overrightarrow{B})$ and they transform correctly under the new  generator $K'_z$
\begin{gather}
K'_z = P^{-1} K_z P =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}
The way I found $P$ was basically by noticing that in the old basis $\Psi = (U_1,U_2,U_3,V_1,V_2,V_3)$ the transformation yields something that looks like doubled lorentz transformations:
\begin{equation}
(\textit{1} + \beta K)\Psi = ( U_1 + i\beta U_2 , U_2 - i\beta U_1, U_3, ..,V_3)
\end{equation}
and since $U_i,V_i \in \mathbb{C}$ the first component becomes:
\begin{equation}
U_1 + i\beta U_2 = \Re(U_1) - \beta \Im(U_2) + i(\Im(U_1) + \beta \Re(U_2))
\end{equation}
Comparing these with the e.m. fields under a boost, it's easy to see that
\begin{equation}
\Re(U_i) = E_i, \\ Im(U_i) = B_i \\\Re(V_i) = B_i \\ Im(V_i) = E_i
\end{equation}
Of course, it is much easier to use the antisymmetric tensor representation $F_{\mu \nu}$. But it can be done!
